# Help me manage a Vampire homebrew roleplay issue

Tags: pathfinder-1e, homebrew

I have a (8th level) Magus [Skirnir archetype, so, casting using shields as a catalyst, etc. Not entirely relevant] who, for the sake of roleplay, is an exile from Kelesh who was removed due to his graverobbing tendencies in regards to Ancient Osirian culture. (As a Magus, he's basically a spell-casting battle-scholar, if you're unfamiliar)
When he was at third level, he was bitten by a sort of homebrew Vampire. It was basically a generic vampire you'd see in the movies (no sparkles) The bite mark left scars, and he had a chance to kill his grandsire before the curse became permanent (homebrew), but opted not to. (Wants to hang around the world a bit longer to study more, kind of like a lich minus the rotting flesh. Bit of a moral lapse there, he's neutralish and has below average Wisdom but huge Intelligence)

Now, my DM and I decided that the way we were going to manage this is that we'll treat level gains as an option between Magus and Vampirism, based on the powers I utilize, where each level gain in Vampirism as opposed to another class I'll gain dark powers of some sort (i.e. the associated Strength bonus, Natural Armor, other Ability bonuses, Mistform, etc.) but my weaknesses related to Vampirism will increase. (Sunlight damage, further aversion to holy symbols and places, maybe a weakness to garlic, etc.)

Now, in terms of roleplay, my character is now 8th level, (6th Magus, 2nd Vampirism) is a little wiser, and has decided that the long term (in terms of his immortal soul) is kinda important.

He's not exactly a bad guy (he typically opts to subsist on animal blood, which we've determined is only feasible at low levels and comes at the cost of some of my dark powers) and he's heard rumors of 'living vampires' (Not homebrew, actually canon) who have managed to preserve at least parts of their original 'humanoid' soul. Without the use of homebrewing the ever loving shite out of everything, is there any feasible way for my character to go about this in terms of a long-term un-life's mission? Magic pertaining to souls, scholarly work in regards to the nature of souls as it relates to the Pathfinder universe, etc.

If it ends in him failing and becoming some kind of mindless soul-eating blood-drinking demon, regardless of the consequences, it's still desirable in terms of roleplay.

TL;DR version: My character is a scholar/genius battle-mage dude with a knack for wondrous items and spell-crafting and scroll-writing who accidentally the whole vampire

He wants to keep his soul, what should he do? (Phylactery lichdom is out of the question, that's just two steps forward and eight steps back in this case)

Comment: I feel like there's a sentence missing before "any feasible way for my character to go about this". This, what? Becoming one of the soul-ful vampires mentioned in the previous sentence? More generically retain his soul? Regain his soul? (Is it still there, or lost already?) Something else?

Comment: Any one of those things pertaining to souls. My guy is trying to figure out what's what in a scholarly fashion, retain some semblance of humanity/his soul, etc.

Comment: He's not beyond torturing other lesser vampires for the purpose of information/knowledge or even experimentation. He's a bit of a mad scientist type. Also, his alignment is a little unclear behaviorally (obviously he is to a degree inherently evil as a vampire)

Comment: Without a clear goal, we can't really provide a solution that meets it. It sounds like "how to pursue any of those things pertaining to souls" is something you've got good leads on already, and you just need to get in the playtime to execute on that pursuit in-game now. Is there a more specific out-of-game help we could provide?

Comment: I know, that's basically exactly what I want. But for the purpose of role-playing, my character's knowledge skills are really high, and I'm just trying to figure out what the desirable course of action is from his perspective. I'm basically asking for people to help me speculate what /he/ would do in this situation given knowledge base and understanding of magic (which exceeds my own, certainly, considering I'm somewhat inexperienced in terms of actually playing)

Comment: OOH. I understand the disconnect I'm seeing now. Unfortunately, speculation is something we're not set up to deliver. If you want people to just put in 2¢ on what you should do next / what would be sensible based on his personality, a forum site is what you were looking for. We only really handle concretely-answerable questions; quoting our [tour]: "Not all questions work well in our format. Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers."

Comment: Pathfinder society is the organized play org - there is no home brew therein, those tags are incompatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Yes, you can retain your soul.

According to the [Dead](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Dead) condition, not having a constitution score is an "effect" and so is vampirism being an effect - that kills you outright. If you wish to retain your soul, without resorting to lichdom, then having a spellcaster that can cast 9th level spells and some expensive jewelry available would allow [Soul Bind](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Soul_Bind).

If there is any confusion on whether or not you are "dead" then look at the description for the [undead](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Undead_Type) type: *Undead are once-living creatures* animated by spiritual or supernatural forces.

It is a little unclear what can be done with your soul once it is bound to a gem, besides being used as currency in outer planes or fuel for magic item creation, but you would have it, literally. But since you are already in a homebrew situation, your DM could state that your soul returns to your lifeless body, at least allowing Raise Dead to be cast on you.

Comment: Do not reproduce copyrighted content, especially without comment.

Comment: @TheNeeoo Do not ask new questions in comments.